# AttributeError: module 'directories' has no attribute 'data_dir'

Tags: python

I have this problem while trying to recognize objects through DQN and loading the vgg16 model. How can I help you solve this problem?

```
import directories
class State:
   cnn_model = load_model(os.path.join(directories.data_dir, "vgg16.h5"))
   feature_extractor = K.function([cnn_model.layers[0].input], [cnn_model.layers[20].output])



cnn_model = load_model(os.path.join(directories.data_dir, "vgg16.h5"))
AttributeError: module 'directories' has no attribute 'data_dir'
```

Comment: What is `directories`? Is it a module that you've `pip install`ed? Is it your own module?

Comment: Yes, this module was installed using pip install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [this module](https://github.com/btr1975/directories/blob/master/directories/directories_class.py), `data_dir` is an instance field on instances of the `Directories` class, not a module attribute. It exists on instances of the `Directories` class, but of course if you just made an instance of that class then you already *have* that variable anyway. So that field is intended to be decided by *you*; it is not functionality that the module provides.